# how to fix these vulnerabilities in react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I am trying to create an app using react native. I am new to react native and when trying install anything with npm and I this I am asked to run npm audit and get the following.

[image: error]

[image: error 2]

[image: error 3]

[image: error 4]

[image: error 5]

[image: error 6]

[image: error 7]

[image: error 8]

[image: error 9]

how do I fix this? I have tried googling it but nothing has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are vulnerabilities of the dependencies you have added, not something to do with your application. For now, i wouldn't worry so much, i would also swap over to using Yarn. In my experience, it tends to play a lot nicer with React Native projects.

Comment: strange as I never added those dependencies

Comment: it is a reference to a sub dependency. You can tell this via the row that shows the path of where the vulnerability exists.